# Multiple linear regression or simple linear regression on residuals

Tags: multiple-regression, residuals

I have several small datasets of few (9 to 12) observations each, and I do have to treat these datasets separately. For each dataset, I want to test for the relative contribution of two continuous predictors on my response variable. More precisely, I am more interest in one predictor (lets call it $X1$), but I have have to take the effect of the second predictor ($X2$) into consideration to "retrieve" it from the relationship between $Y$ and $X1$.

$Y = intercept + aX1 + bX2 + e$ ($X1$ and $X2$ both continuous and non-collinear)

I know that testing the effect of two predictors with as few as 9 to 12 observations is tricky! Thus, I am using the R function `'summ'` (after a classical `lm()`)from the package **`jtools`** to get the mean + confidence intervals of each estimate (a and b) after standardization (R function `'standardize'`); and get a general idea of the effect size of each predictor for each of my small datasets eventhough I get something non-significant (which is, expectedly, often the case).

Here are my questions:

- Is that OK to do multiple linear regression to get the estimation (+CIs) of $a$ (the slope of $X1$), and only use this estimation in further analyses? In other terms: can I then consider I am actually reporting the proper, remaining effect of X1 on Y after accounting for the effect of $X2$?
- Should I run a separate model first (i.e., $Y = bX2 + e$), get the residuals, and then (and only then) fit a model with residuals($Y.X2) = aX1 + e$ ? Is there any difference (I would intuitively say there is not!) between this and what I was describing formerly?

Thank you all for your answers! Still learning about secrets of statistics but hoping to get better at it very soon :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, multiple regression with only 9-12 observations will not be extremely helpful...  Could you do it?  Yes.  Is it mathematically sound?  Yes.  Is it helpful in predicting future values or estimating the relationship?  Most likely, no.

Comment: `lm()` in R is the standard (single and multiple) linear regression function, in case you are wondering about it.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your answers, ERT. I indeed used the lm() function to get estimates of the a and b slopes (I have added the info on my question). I know I have few observations, unfortunately I have no choice but dealing with it. Though, since I am reporting both estimates and CIs (even though these are wide), I was hoping to work with these estimates afterwards, tempering this with regard to effect sizes (i.e. interpreting results with high caution) but I was not sure to be right, in particular regarding the two questions above. Thank you again!

Comment: I would suggest to try and use a bayesian regression approach. Especially in cases where you have only a few observations this approach gives you a better impression how "confident" you can be about your coefficients (credible interval) $a$ and $b$. In addition you can use your knowledge as a "scientists" to define priors about the outcomes of  the coefficients.

Comment: I don't see any reason in your narrative for testing the effect of $X_2$: you need to control for it, so do so.  That leaves you with 6 to 9 degrees of freedom to test $X_1$ in each case, which could suffice.  To the extent your models might have a common value of some parameter (for instance, the variance of the errors, or perhaps even the intercept or the $X_2$ coefficient), you could "borrow strength" by fitting them all at once.  One might view this as a classical version of the Bayesian approach suggested by @burton.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! I will just keep going with my two-predictors model then (and forget about my second question) to extract the effect of $X1$ while controlling for $X2$. I will try the bayesian approach too. I know the R package `MCMCglmm` handles this quite well for mixed models, but apparently there is a `bayes.lm()` function from the package `Bolstad` for fixed effects. 

Thanks you whuber for your suggestion: though I do not have common parameter values, this could be of high interest for further analyses!
Cheers!